# Java - Writing the body of an abstract class in the subclass constructor

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class

When defining an abstract class, it is possible to create an instance of that class by writing the body of the abstract methods at object definition, like this:

```
AbstractClass obj = new AbstractClass() {   
   protected String description() {   return this.description;   }   
};
```

I would like to do something similar, but inside the constructor of a sub-class. Something like this:

```
public class AbstractClass {
   String description;
   public AbstractClass(String description){
       this.description = description;
   }
   protected abstract String description();
}
public class ActualClass extends AbstractClass {
   public ActualClass(String description){
       super(description) {
       protected String description() {    return this.description;    }
       };
   }
}
```

Now, the code above doesn't work. How could I do something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't do it in constructor, but in the class itself:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    String description;
    public AbstractClass(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    protected abstract String description();
}

public class ActualClass extends AbstractClass {
    public ActualClass(String description){
        super(description);
    }

    protected String description() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```